# Azure 2.2 - Use IIS WebServer option disabled?

Tags: c#, iis, azure

Using the latest Azure, in the projects local development server option, the 'Use IIS WebServer' option is disabled. See the following screenshot:

[image: No full IIS option]

However, on the Microsoft Docs, I found for [using Full IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsazure/jj156006) just says: `5. Click Use IIS Web Server.`

Any details on why this wouldn't work properly or is not enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enable "Full Emulator" to unblock Full IIS option.